# Error: Number of columns is inconsistent on line 5 - While parsing CSV

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, parsing, fs

I am attempting to parse a CSV file that uses tabs as column delimiter. I am getting the error below:

```
Error: Number of columns is inconsistent on line 5
at Parser.__push (/Users/mesamhaider/Desktop/workspace/Order_CSV_Parsing_Tool/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/index.js:248:14)
at Parser.__write (/Users/mesamhaider/Desktop/workspace/Order_CSV_Parsing_Tool/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/index.js:469:20)
at Parser._transform (/Users/mesamhaider/Desktop/workspace/Order_CSV_Parsing_Tool/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/index.js:182:14)
at Parser.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:190:10)
at Parser.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:178:12)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:371:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:357:5)
at Parser.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:274:11)
at ReadStream.ondata (_stream_readable.js:626:20)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
```

The code that I am using is shown below:

```
const fs = require('fs'); 
const parse = require('csv-parse'); 

 fs.createReadStream('../in/*.csv')
     .pipe(parse({delimiter : '  '}))
     .on('data', function(row){ 
        console.log(row)
    })
```

The code will do much more than logging it to the console but for example's purpose, I put it this way. Also - once I parse this would it be possible to input each column inside of a SQL insert statement?

Comment: Is your CSV file valid, with consistent number of columns in each row?

Comment: @koolkat - yes i assume that it is. However, there are some columns that do not hold a value for certain rows. Could that be causing this issue?

Comment: That shouldn't cause an issue, since empty values are interpreted as empty strings `' '`. Try validating your `CSV` using an online `CSV linter`.

Comment: You "assume" that it is valid? Perhaps you could [edit] your question to show an example of the file that is failing (or just the first half-dozen lines, given that the error mentions line 5).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code for you. Please install `should` node module for this code to run.

- You create the parser with `parser()` function
- Write inside it with `write()` function
- retrieve data with `on.finish()`.

  ```
  const fs = require('fs'); 
  const parse = require('csv-parse'); 
  require("should");

  var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream('../in/*.csv');

  var parser = parse({delimiter: ':'});

  parser.write(myReadStream);

  parser.on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err.message);
  });

  parser.on('finish', function(){
    output.should.eql([Bunch of arrays here from the file]);
  });
  ```

See here for more [information.](http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/examples/)